# tr not impacting file command output

Tags: file, unix, space, trim, tr

If I run:

```
$ ls -l /tmp
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 noaccess noaccess     177 Nov 18 09:53 hsperfdata_noaccess
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         117 Nov 18 09:53 hsperfdata_root
```

I get the expected result running:

```
]$ ls -l /tmp | tr -s '[:space:]'
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 noaccess noaccess 177 Nov 18 09:53 hsperfdata_noaccess
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 117 Nov 18 09:53 hsperfdata_root
```

Yet `tr` will not impact `file` output:

```
$ file /tmp/dummy
/tmp/dummy:     empty file

$ file /tmp/dummy | tr -s '[:space:]'
/tmp/dummy:     empty file
```

(the same if I use `[:blank:]`)

I was expecting:

```
$ file /tmp/dummy | tr -s '[:space:]'
/tmp/dummy: empty file
```

Am I misusing `file`? `tr`? Must I `awk`? I'm using bash 3.2.51 on SunOS 5.10 and would like to tell XML and gz files apart.

Answer (score 1):

The Solaris 5.10 version of `file` is producing output that uses tabs instead of spaces:

```
$ touch /tmp/dummy
$ file /tmp/dummy | cat -vet
/tmp/dummy:^Iempty file$
$
```

In this case, `tr -s` squashes a single tab character down to a single tab character...